# Term for numbers that have at least one non-zero significant digit after the decimal point?

Tags: adjectives, terminology, mathematics, fractions

So, a number that is nothing but fractions is "fractional". A number that has a whole number and a fraction is "mixed", if you want to call it that. And the portion after the decimal point is called the mantissa in at least some (all?) contexts, although many would not know this word. But how about numbers that have a whole part and a non-zero mantissa, such as **1.93** or **159.2** or **-0.8**, as opposed to 5 or 5.00? What do you call those in more or less conversational English?

Comment: Real numbers.  Are you looking for a term describing some subset of the reals? Like non-integer reals? "Decimal" and "floating point" have certain connotations in computing.  Floating point means the potentially imprecise representation of a real, while decimal implies the precise representation of a base-10 real number...

Comment: @stevesliva: I've modified the question; "real" is of course correct, but not particularly useful to describe numbers to most people that aren't e.g. professional mathematicians/programmers. Maybe tags are still wrong, though.

Comment: I would have thought it's just "decimals."  Like you "learn decimals" in grade school, in that you discover what a decimal point is for. It also matches fairly well with the comp-sci definition of "decimal number."

Comment: @stevesliva, I've not seen the adjective form of decimal, used in the narrow sense here, outside CS. (Even in CS, it's far more about numbers that are stored in a particular way than about numbers that definitely have a mantissa attached.)

Comment: The word "mantissa" has multiple uses and with your new edit, I am do not know what meaning you are using. Three links: this seems to be close to how you are using the word http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mantissa.html; or as a synonym of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand; or as the fractional portion of the common log https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantissa. Which definition are you using? Maybe use bold or italics to highlight the exact digits you want a name for.

Comment: @HunterHogan: OK, bolded. Wolfram's definition appears to coincide quite closely with what I'm saying, yes.

Comment: I'm still confused because using the word mantissa as your criteria for grouping your examples, your sets of numbers do not follow the Wolfram definition. With the number 5.00 the mantissa is .00 because it is the floor of .00. I also think I am confused by your use of the words fractional and mixed. It seems that maybe you you mean a fraction number is greater than zero and less than 1. Your example of -0.8 as belonging the in the same category as 1.93 is confusing to me. A fractional number is not a type of number, it is a way to write a number. A rational number, though, is a type of number

Comment: @HunterHogan: I'm not concerned with numbers that *are* mantissas, but those that *have* (non-zero) mantissas. .00 is the same as zero, and .93 is not; therefore only the latter should be included.

Comment: It's a little sad that this question has to be so precisely caged about with mathematical terminology when I was desiring a term for fairly plain usages. But oh well, can't help that I guess.

Comment: You are using a mathematical term of art, not a colloquial term. In math, .00 is not necessarily equal to 0 because of significant figures. This has real world applications in many sciences, especially physics, chemistry, and microbiology. Maybe you are looking for "non-whole number," in the colloquial sense.

Comment: @HunterHogan: 0.00 isn't equal to 0; .00, to my knowledge, is zero, or at least is not non-zero. (Given that it is not possible to take a measurement that comes to ".00" in any correct sense.)

Comment: This is my last comment. "Trailing zeros in a number containing a decimal point are significant." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures This stuff matters. If it didn't matter, space exploration would not be possible nor would particle physics nor would many other fields that rely on precision. Mathematics is the discipline that is the most concerned with eliminating ambiguity. There are exceptionally precise rules for when 0.00 = 0 and when the quantities are not equal.

Comment: hh is right.  But this is not the place to give a tutorial on significant figures or error bars.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comments, I truly think [**Decimal**](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=decimal) is the word you're looking for.

It is used in everyday language to mean precisely what you want it to.

Furthermore, if you have a separate category of "integers" or "whole numbers," it would be absolutely clear what a "decimal" category would mean.

Comment: This is peculiar, because it does not sound familiar to me. "Mixed decimal", though, I could understand fairly well. Maybe that will do the job. E: Or more citations/quoted usages would help I guess.

Comment: Outside math and computer science, it's just "decimal number."  In common usage, that signifies having a decimal point, *not* being base 10.  And the "number" is implicit in "decimals" the same way it is in "fractions."

Comment: Hmm, looks like one of the related questions in the sidebar uses decimal in this sense. OK, can't really argue with that.

Comment: "Decimals" as a noun is perhaps less common as non-integer numbers of all varieties become more ubiquitous and more precise terms gain more traction.  But it would most definitely have been the answer 30 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

A noninteger.

Cf. [integer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/integer) at dictionary.com.

Ugly word, though, considering 'in-' itself stands for 'non-'.

Comment: It might be edifying to continue this etymology rant to its conclusion. :) If *in-* means *non-*, and *teger* means *touchable*, integers are untouchable and non integers mean not untouchable. :)

Comment: Nonintegral might also work for the adjective form, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a specific word for those digits in the same way that "remainder" has a mathematical meaning when performing integer division.

Nevertheless, some words can well describe the digits to which you refer. The Wikipedia article on [Significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) implies many options.

1. **Overestimated** value (in most cases) because a significant figure is a [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), additional non-zero digits after the significant digits increase the value of the number from its "precise" value.
2. **Spurious** digit(s)
3. **Extraneous** digit(s)
4. **Imprecise** digit(s)
5. **Falsely precise** value
6. **Non-normalized** digit(s)/value
7. **Non-confident** (In-confident? Un-confident? Poopy-confident?) digit(s)

You should publish a paper in a journal about this problem, and then we can call the digits improperly appended to significant figures "Tuggy digits."

Comment: Edited question to clarify a bit more; I'm not so concerned with *false* precision as with numbers that happen to have any precision beyond the integral at all, and, colloquially, "need" that precision.